# How much faster is “D-Wave Two” compared to its predecessor?

Tags: experimental-realization, performance, annealing, d-wave

I don't have any specific task or algorithm in mind, so depending on how they were tested – Is there any research which shows just how the [D-Wave Two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Wave_Two) computer was faster (in terms of computation performance) than its predecessor (D-Wave One)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Troyer and Lidar saw no speed increase with the D-Wave 1 compared to classical computers, the D-Wave 2 [benchmark figure reported in 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Wave_Systems#cite_note-44) of 3600 times as fast as CPLEX (the best algorithm on a conventional machine) suggests the D-Wave 2 is 3600 times as fast as the D-Wave 1.

However:

- the results are in a pretty restricted set of parameters, so this may not be relevant for other parameters. (as an example, the benchmark figures for the D-Wave 2000Q only take constant factor performance gains into account)
- the configuration of the CPLEX may not compare directly to the classical computers used to benchmark the D-Wave 1

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know the closest answer to your question for applications is given in the recent (still unpublished) work presented at the [March meeting](http://meetings.aps.org/Meeting/MAR18/Session/S28.6) by Bibek Pokharel, where he compares graph 3-coloring instances on D-Wave Two, D-Wave 2X and D-Wave 2000Q, all other things staying reasonably equal. 
The short answer is that all the performance increase is essentially due to the possibility to run single anneals at shorter anneal-time. (e.g. 1$\mu$s instead of 5$\mu$s gives indeed about 5X of performance increase, in terms of time-to-solution (TTS) metric. With respect to 20$\mu$s of D-Wave Two the scaling is different).

I can also spoil that from D-Wave Two and D-Wave 2000Q on [Sherrington-Kirkpatrick instances](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.5.031040) we observed no substantial improvement as well. Results will be published soon in collaborations with Stanford.